# Does CPAN have a SQLite module that does not depend on DBI?

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi

I need to be able to query a SQLite DB from my Perl code.

Unfortunately, the platform does not have [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI), let alone [`DBD::SQLite`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3aSQLite) and my sysadmin has made life difficult for me in this regard.

It would be nice if I could simply make `DBI` and `DBD::SQLite` a part of my codebase, but it looks like it needs to be run through `cpan` for it to work.

So, it there any DBI-independent module <sub>(no pun intended)</sub> that I can make use of?

Comment: `cpan` is not needed to install these modules. `cpan` does not even install modules per say; it simply calls the Makefile.PL or Build.PL that comes in the distro.

Comment: Futhermore, one can install modules to any directory, so special permissions are not need to install a module.

Comment: You may find perlbrew helpful here, it will make you a copy of perl that is not controlled by your sysadmin.

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [How can I install a CPAN module into a local directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory)

Comment: If you're using Perl without the ability to install modules from CPAN then you're making your life unnecessarily difficult. I strongly recommend that you upgrade your sysadmin, your manager or your job :)

Answer (score -1):

Will this thread will be helpful to you? looks like similar discussion.

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=619077