# Having trouble installing Perl modules using cpan

Tags: perl, cpan

Had to download Command Line Tools from Apple to get make to work, but not sure if that's still the problem here?

```
cpan[8]> install HTML::Template
Running install for module 'HTML::Template'
Running make for W/WO/WONKO/HTML-Template-2.91.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /Users/jaldama/.cpan/build/HTML-Template-2.91-    0bPiwL
  Has already been made
Running make test
  Has already been tested successfully
Running make install
Already tried without success
```

Comment: To see the real error message, restart the CPAN shell and try again.  I guess you simply do not have permissions to install to the system location. On OS X it is best to leave the system Perl alone; either [install your own Perl](http://perlbrew.pl), or [install the libraries to your home directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory).

Comment: try `ppm install HTML::Template` on cmd line.

Comment: Why is it best to leave system Perl alone?

Comment: Because Apple like to screw up the system installation, and then you have to repair the mess they made. Therefore, better to run your own separate Perl that's fully under your control. http://use.perl.org/use.perl.org/_jk2addict/journal/38503.html http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/02/16/apple_update_perl_breakage/ http://perlnews.org/2011/04/dealing-with-xcode-4-and-cpan-breakage/ http://markmail.org/thread/j3s536r75u2q3has http://mjo.tc/atelier/2011/03/xcode4-perl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up running as root for now which solved the apparent permission problem, but I will be ffollowing @daxim 's advice on keeping my own Perl separate.