# How to unset / remove INSTALL_BASE from cpan?

Tags: perl, cpan

I previously set INSTALL_BASE following the instruction here: [How can I use a new Perl module without install permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251705/how-can-i-use-a-new-perl-module-without-install-permissions)

But then it didn't work for me, and decided to use cpanminus with local::lib instead following this instruction: [How can I use CPAN as a non-root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980297/how-can-i-use-cpan-as-a-non-root-user)

But I got this error message:

WHOA THERE! It looks like you've got INSTALL_BASE= set. This is
known to cause problems with local::lib. Please either remove this setting or
clear out your .cpan directory.

How to unset / remove INSTALL_BASE from cpan?
I spent considerable time googling for it but couldn't find anything that worked.

Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering around, I came up with:

o conf makepl_arg ''

o conf mbuild_arg ''

o conf commit

This does seem to work?

Comment: Found another thread where somebody managed to create similarly problematic build settings. The "fix/reset" step in this answer looks similar to your suggested commands: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14699051/1251354