# Can't locate Bench.pm in @INC [Perl]

Tags: perl

I have a problem when i compile my perl program :
it mention :

> Can't locate Bench.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at test.pl line 4.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 4.

Any idea please?
Thanks

Comment: Have you actually installed Bench?

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=frequent):
[What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module) [How can I install a CPAN module into a local directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory)

Answer (score 3):

Install [Bench](http://p3rl.org/Bench) as you would any other CPAN module, e.g. with [cpanm](http://p3rl.org/cpanm), [cpanp](http://p3rl.org/cpanp) or [cpan](http://p3rl.org/cpan).

You might want to first use [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) to install a local (and newer) version of Perl so you won't be touching anything related to the system Perl installation.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if you have installed Bench module:

```
%> perl -MBench -e 1
```

If you get the error message, you have to install it:

```
%> cpan Bench
```

Comment: cpan install Bench
It looks like you specified 'install' as an argument to cpan(1). This
script is not the CPAN.pm prompt and doesn't understand the same commands.
In fact, doesn't require the extra typing. You probably just want to
list the modules you want to install:

 cpan Bench
 
See the documentation for more details on using this script.

Comment: try simply "cpan Bench"

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your answer to change it it to `cpan Bench`