# Why do I get a red wavy underline in Komodo Edit when I try to load the NetAddr::IP library?

Tags: perl, syntax-highlighting, perl-module, importerror, komodoedit

How do I load the NetAddr::IP library? I'm getting a red wavy underline in Komodo Edit.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use NetAddr::IP;
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

my $page = new CGI;
print $page->header;
my $ipaddress = $page->param("ip");
my $ip = NetAddr::IP->new($ipaddress);
print "The address is ", $ip->addr, " with mask ", $ip->mask, "\n" ;
```

[image: Komodo Edit screenshot]

Comment: Is it executing? Or are you just getting a line ?

Comment: What happens if you run: `perl -MNetAddr::IP -e 1` from your shell/console?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen it is not ececuting

Comment: @chrsblck getting this 'moeez.pl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You can't figure out a mask from an IP.

Answer (score 0):

The module simply is not installed. Install it.

From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=frequent):

- [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)
- [How can I install a CPAN module into a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory)

Comment: I am using Windowns and using Komodo Edit.