# How to do map path to completion in Perl/Tk

Tags: perl, perltk

The linux system in my server comes with Perl v5.14.1, and it seems like this version of Perl do not support Tk-PathEntry widget (pls refer to : https://code.activestate.com/ppm/Tk-PathEntry/).  May I know is there any alternate way that I can do so that I can map path to completion in entry widgets for the sample script I get somewhere such as below?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Tk;
use Tk::PathEntry;

use Cwd;

$path = cwd();

$mw = MainWindow->new();
$mw->geometry( '300x80' );
$mw->resizable( 0, 0 );

$mw->PathEntry( -textvariable=>\$path )->pack;
$mw->Label( -textvariable=>\$path, -foreground=>'blue' )->pack;
$mw->Button( -text=>'Quit', -command=>sub{ exit } )->pack;

MainLoop;
```

The error msg that I get as such, seem like the Perl version that I'm pointing to is not supporting the PathEntry widget:-
 Assuming 'require Tk::PathEntry;' at path.ptk line 14
Can't locate Tk/PathEntry.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /nfs/disks/my_work/scripts/Tk-PathEntry-2.23/lib /usr/pkgs/5.14.1/lib64/site_perl/x86_64-linux /usr/pkgs/perl/5.14.1/lib64/site_perl /usr/pkgs/perl/5.14.1/lib64/5.14.1/x86_64-linux /usr/pkgs/perl/5.14.1/lib64/5.14.1 /usr/pkgs/perl/5.14.1/lib64/module/default/x86_64-linux /usr/pkgs/perl/5.14.1/lib64/module/default .) at /usr/pkgs/perl/5.14.1/lib64/module/default/x86_64-linux/Tk/Widget.pm line 270

Pls advice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install this modul locally, without root rights and package with your script.

You could use local::lib to make it easier but it may enough:

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=./modules
make
make install
```

See details in this post to do it easier: [How can I install a CPAN module into a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory)

Comment: thanks for the links and comment but I some how fail to do that.

Comment: Reading the material all again, and finally I got it.  Thanks a bunch.