# INSTALL_BASE seems to be ignored by Makefile.PL

Tags: perl

I am trying out some some custom modifications for the [`Template`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) module. I downloaded it using:

```
$ cpan -g Template
```

Next, I wanted to install it into a custom folder such that my debug
version did not overwrite the original installation.

I did a quick Google search, and found [`How can I install a CPAN module into a local directory?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/540640/2173773). According to that answer, I determined that I should be using `INSTALL_BASE`, for example:

```
perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/home/hakon/perl/debug/lib
make
make install
```

But this does not work, it still installs (and overwrites) into the `PERL5LIB` directory where I have the installed the original module using `cpanm`. My path to 
`PERL5LIB` is `/home/hakon/perl5`. When I inspect the `Makefile` created by `Makefile.PL`,  I can see that on line 21 there is:

```
#     INSTALL_BASE => q[/home/hakon/perl/debug/lib]
```

(note the comment in front), whereas on line 86 I have:

```
INSTALL_BASE = /home/hakon/perl5
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/tTiJGFhU) is the whole Makefile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing `INSTALL_BASE=/home/hakon/perl5` to MakeMaker using env var `PERL_MM_OPT`. Unset it; it's overriding your command-line option.

Alternatively, set the env var instead of passing an argument.

```
export PERL_MM_OPT='INSTALL_BASE=/home/hakon/perl/debug/lib'
export PERL_MB_OPT='--install_base /home/hakon/perl/debug/lib'
cpan/cpanm/Makefile.PL/Build.PL ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I tried `PERL_MM_OPT= perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/home/hakon/perl/debug/lib`.

Comment: Alternatively, `PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/home/hakon/perl/debug/lib perl Makefile.PL`