# Installing Perl modules to a specific location

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

I have several Linux machines that run Perl programs and other programs and tools.

I want to keep all tools between machines synchronized, so I have shared the `/usr/local` directory between one machine (Main) and the others.

Now I would like to keep all my Perl modules and their dependencies synchronized as well in `/usr/local/<path to modules>`.

I have found the [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) module, but that is intended to install modules to your home directory.

How can I set up CPAN (or CPAN alternatives) to install all modules and dependencies to one location? And how can I set up Perl on other machines to use that location to find modules?

Comment: You can tell local::lib where to install things.

Comment: Are you hoping to install modules to be accessed from a different machine? I don't like the sound of that.

Comment: See also [INSTALL_BASE seems to be ignored by Makefile.PL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41191384/2173773)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For our convenience, let's assign the base location to a variable: (This var isn't used by anything but the following commands. There's actually no need to `export` it.)

```
export PERL_BASE="/usr/local/perl"   # Or "$HOME" or whatever
```

Instruct ExtUtils::MakeMaker where to install: (This assumes `$PERL_BASE` doesn't include any shell metacharacters)

```
export PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=$PERL_BASE"
```

Instruct Module::Build where to install: (This assumes `$PERL_BASE` doesn't include any shell metacharacters)

```
export PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base $PERL_BASE"
```

Instruct Perl where to look for modules: (This assumes `$PERL_BASE` doesn't include `:`)

```
export PERL5LIB="$PERL_BASE/lib/perl5"
```

Instruct the system where to look for scripts: (This assumes `$PERL_BASE` doesn't include `:`)

```
export PATH="$PERL_BASE/bin${PATH:+:$PATH}"
```

Instruct the system where to look for man pages: (This assumes `$PERL_BASE` doesn't include `:`)

```
export MANPATH="$PERL_BASE/man${MANPATH:+:$MANPATH}"
```

---

All together:

```
export PERL_BASE="/usr/local/perl"
export PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=$PERL_BASE"
export PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base $PERL_BASE"
export PERL5LIB="$PERL_BASE/lib/perl5"
export PATH="$PERL_BASE/bin${PATH:+:$PATH}"
export MANPATH="$PERL_BASE/man${MANPATH:+:$MANPATH}"
```

Answer (score 4):

[local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) can be set up at any location, the location `~/perl5` is just a default:

```
# set up PERL_MM_OPT, PERL_MB_OPT, PERL5LIB, and other shell variables
eval "$(perl -I/opt/perllib/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=/opt/perllib)"
```

The [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanm) CPAN installer can install to any location as if it were a local::lib, regardless of how your environment is configured (whether by local::lib or other means):

```
cpanm -l /opt/perllib Some::Module
```

You can make use of any local::lib installation without having enabled it by adding the lib dir using `PERL5LIB` or [lib](https://perldoc.pl/lib) or the `-I` switch, and using the path to executables in the local::lib bin dir if needed:

```
PERL5LIB=/opt/perllib/lib/perl5 /path/to/script.pl
perl -Mlib=/opt/perllib/lib/perl5 ./script.pl
perl -I/opt/perllib/lib/perl5 /opt/perllib/bin/mojo version
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my own previous misadventures with `local::lib`, you should be able to set the location where modules are installed by setting `INSTALL_BASE` in `PERL_MM_OPT`, most likely by running a command similar to:

```
export PERL_MM_OPT='INSTALL_BASE=/usr/local/<path to modules>'
```

Alternately, if you're doing the Makefile/make/make test/make install process manually instead of using the CPAN toolchain, you can pass `--install_base=/usr/local/<path to modules>` as an argument to `Makefile.PL`.

Comment: `'--INSTALL_BASE' is not a known MakeMaker parameter name.`?

Answer (score -1):

you could use the following bash [func](https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/min-perl-wrapp/blob/master/src/bash/deploy/ubuntu/ubuntu-20.04.2-lts/check-install-perl-modules.func.sh) ...

```
 do_check_install_perl_modules(){

      
     local_perl5dir=~/perl5
     bash_opts_file=~/.bashrc

     wget -O- http://cpanmin.us | perl - -l ~/perl5 App::cpanminus local::lib
     eval `perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib`
     echo 'eval `perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib`' >> ~/.bashrc
     echo 'export MANPATH=$HOME/perl5/man:$MANPATH' >> ~/.bashrc

     modules="$(cat ${BASH_SOURCE/.func.sh/.lst})"
     while read -r module ; do use_modules="${use_modules:-} use $module ; "; done < <(echo "$modules");

     perl -e "$use_modules" || {
        echo "deploying modules. This WILL at least 4 min, but ONLY ONCE !!!"
        test "$(grep -c 'Mlocal::lib' $bash_opts_file|xargs)" -eq 0 && \
           echo 'eval $(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)' >> $bash_opts_file
                  while read -r module ; do cpanm_modules="${cpanm_modules:-} $module " ; done < <(echo "$modules")
       
       cmd="cpanm --local-lib=$local_perl5dir $modules"
        $cmd
        set +e
                  }
  }
```