# Can't locate in @INC during CPAN dependency install performed not as root

Tags: perl, installation, cpan

While trying to do:

```
perl -I'/v1/data/site_perl' -MCPAN -e 'install Log::Dispatch';
```

I continue to get "Can't locate Params/Validate.pm in @INC."  When looking at the output, /v1/data/site_perl is NOT in the @INC displayed, even though I used -I.

I am not root so I have changed my CPAN config so that:

```
'makepl_arg' => q[LIB=/v1/data/site_perl INSTALLSITEMAN1DIR=/v1/data/site_perl/man/man1 INSTALLSITEMAN3DIR=/v1/data/site_perl/man/man3 INSTALLMAN1DIR=/v1/data/site_perl/man/man1 INSTALLMAN3DIR=/v1/data/site_perl/man/man3]
```

So even LIB is set.

In a basic script I have:

```
use lib '/v1/data/site_perl';
use Params::Validate;
```

With no problems.

How do I make the Log::Dispatch use lib /v1/data/site_perl without a force install?  What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102850/how-can-i-install-cpan-modules-locally-without-root-access-dynaloader-pm-line-22 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe CPAN.pm likes to call a lot of sub-processes for various tasks, and these end up starting new `perl`s, which will not inherit your `-I` flag. Instead, try setting a `PERL5LIB` environment variable, e.g.

```
PERL5LIB='/v1/data/site_perl' perl -MCPAN -e 'install Log::Dispatch'
```

Another strategy to consider is to simply build a complete Perl installation in your local directory -- then use *that* perl's CPAN utilities. They will already have all your own paths built-in. This is the way I tend to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot install into a different CPAN directory using a simple `-I` flag.  You can use the [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib) package to install a local set of libraries, or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102850/how-can-i-install-cpan-modules-locally-without-root-access-dynaloader-pm-line-22).

Comment: I used -I to add my non-root lib to @INC.  Once the CPAN got to the primary module, it couldn't find the required recently installed modules because that instance of @INC didn't contain my directory. I didn't try setting PERL5LIB, which worked. local::lib is not installed on that machine, but soon will be!  Thanks for the info.